# How to automaticlly select application when switching workspace

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

When I use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Arrow</kbd> it switches the workspace but the application that is open isn't selected, so then I have to do <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the last application I was last used in the workspace.

How can I automatically switch to the last application I was using in that workspace when switching workspaces?

Comment: If I have an application open in a different workspace, I usually just click on it in the Unity Launcher, this switches the workspace and brings the application in focus all in one go. It's not a keyboard shortcut though.